# How to pass props to children according to type in React + Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, it seems like a basic problem but I wasn't able to find an answer anywhere.

I am trying to find a way to conditionally pass props to children components based on the the type (i.e. component type) of the child.

For instance given a generic functional component

```
const Parent = ({propA, propB, children, ...props}) => (
    <div {...props}>
        {children}
    </div>
)
```

in which I expect to receive only `A` and `B` components as children. I want `propA` to be passed only to children of type `A` and `propB` to be passed only to children of type `B` such that

```
const Parent = ({propA, propB, children, ...props}) => (
  <div {...props}>
      {React.Children.map<React.ReactNode, React.ReactNode>(children, child => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
          if (/* child if of type A */)
            return React.cloneElement(child, { propA })
          if (/* child if of type B */)
            return React.cloneElement(child, { propB })
        }
      })}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the mapping between Component and its respective props, you can create an array of objects and then map over it, while passing it from the parent.
Example

```
//calling of parent
<Parent renderObject = {[
  {prop : propA, comp: compA},
  {prop : propB, comp: compB}
 ]}
 ...restOfTheProps
/>
```

Now you can actually code something like this using map

```
const Parent = ({ renderObject, ...props}) => (
  <div {...props}>
      {renderObject.map((renderObj)=>{
          return <renderObj.comp {...renderObj.prop} />
       })}
  </div>
)
```

instead of using children, you can pass component as props.

Answer (score 0):

You can use child.type

```
const Parent = ({propA, propB, children, ...props}) => (
  <div {...props}>
      {React.Children.map<React.ReactNode, React.ReactNode>(children, child => {
          if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
              if (child.type===A) {
                  return React.cloneElement(child, { propA })
              } else {
              return React.cloneElement(child, { propB })
              }
          }
      })}
   </div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

same this you can do it!

```
<Modal isActive={true} > 
  <h1>Modal here!</h1>
</Modal>
```

and in Your component do same this:

```
type Props ={
  children: React.ReactNode;
  isActive: boolean;
}

const Modal:React.FC<Props> = ({children, isActive}) => {
  return isActive && children;
}
export default Modal;
```